# His hands over his head

Tags: meaning

Source - Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban

Chapter - 20

Context - Harry finds Sirius at the shore of the lake where he is already turned into a human from a dog.

> He was crouched on all fours, his hands over his head.

If the person was crouching on all fours, including the hands, how would the hands be, at the same time, over their head?

Comment: The expression is "on all fours", not "in all fours."  Are you sure you're typing the whole thing out correctly?  Because I agree, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry. Fixed that - it is, in fact, "on the four."

Comment: His head is on the ground.

Comment: If his head is on the ground, would that position be called "on all fours"? It has to be limbs, I suppose?

Comment: Yeah, it's a confusing description by JK Rowling, who is not infallible or some kind of god no matter what her fans believe(d). It might make sense if he was on elbows and knees, but I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: On knees and elbows and head low is how I read it. In that context I think she means that the character, though no longer a dog, is in a timid, dog-like pose.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it needs directing to the author / publisher. It looks illogical.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark You have written an answer. Please actually write an answer.

Comment: it's probably a poor description of something like this: https://images.app.goo.gl/cte19KLKTPrBijbx7

Answer (score 3):

Imagine someone crouching on all fours (knees, feet and hands in contact with the ground), who is then so fearful that they bend lower at the front end, place their hands over their head and place their elbows and possibly also face on the ground. Or, if you would rather, imagine that the author has been a little careless and written something that only a skilled contortionist could feasibly attempt.

Comment: Every definition of 'on all fours' I've checked mandates 'hands' &/or 'arms' on the floor for humans.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: You'll have upvoted my answer for the second sentence then :-)

Comment: I don't know why this answer has been upvoted (I've partly adjusted). And the question belongs elsewhere anyway. In standard English, the sentence makes little sense; if not an oversight (and JKR rarely makes mistakes) it's a matter of literary interpretation.